# How to get values/params from a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have URI route like:

```
/dir/:dir1/:val1-:val2
```

I need a regular expression to:

1. Know if the route match the real URI (es. /category/cars/ferrari-10)
2. Get parameters and values like the follow:

   dir1 => cars

   val1 => ferrari

   val2 => 10

How to do this job?

THank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex named groups and `preg-match`:

```
$test = "/category/cars/ferrari-10";
$result = preg_match("/^\/[^\/]+\/(?P<dir1>[^\/]+)\/(?P<val1>[^-]+)-(?P<val2>[^\/]+)$/", $test, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The above will [result](http://ideone.com/J3q6Q) in the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /category/cars/ferrari-10
    [dir1] => cars
    [1] => cars
    [val1] => ferrari
    [2] => ferrari
    [val2] => 10
    [3] => 10
)
```

Also, if you want to remove the unnamed groups, you can use the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
  unset($matches[$i]);
}
```

#### References:

- [`preg-match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: is it possible to remove automatically [1] => cars  [2] => ferrari and [3] => 10 ?

Comment: no, but why would you need such feature ? If you don't want them, just don't use them

Comment: also, the regex readability could be improved by changing the string delimiter to something other than "/", then you could changes all thoses "\/" to a simpler "/" :)

Comment: @pomeh, I need it because I have to send those parameters/values to a function, but I must to send this clean array. Maybe remove automatically all the odd :)

Comment: @Dail: No, `preg_match` doesn't support that. However, you can use a simple loop to unset the unwanted elements. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Regex may be overkill. May be easier if you separate all values by `/` instead of mixing `/` with `-`.

Then you could use a simple explode.

```
$param_array = explode('/', $original_uri);
```

You could then unshift each value off of the beginning of the array to get the individual values to use to test the route.

```
$controller = array_unshift($param_array);
$action = array_unshift($param_array);
$args = $param_array;
```

Comment: this is what I do. easiest. if they still wanted to use the `-` to separate args then set `$args = array_unshift($param_array); if($args){ $args = explode('-', $args); }`